# Set Ctrl + click as shortcut for right-click in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse

I am used to working with a Wacom tablet to activate the context menu with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>.

How can that be achieved in Ubuntu 17.04?

I know of the shortcut function <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, but I like to fire a right-click event by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>.

Comment: Are you using the default file manager for ubuntu called nautilus??

Comment: @Oriol Gonzalo: Yes, I am using Nautilus.